# Why am I getting the error when executing this simple nodejs program

Tags: node.js

I am trying to execute this simple nodejs code within ubuntu WSL.

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const MyEmitter = New EventEmitter();

myEmitter.emit('TEST_EVENT');

myEmitter.on('TEST_EVENT',()=>
            {console.log('This event was emitted');}
            )
```

**I am getting this error:**

```
ro@Ro-PC:~/ngs/4-modules/7-event-emitters$ node example.js
/home/ro/ngs/4-modules/7-event-emitters/example.js:7
const myEmitter = New EventEmitter();
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Node.js v17.9.0
```

Would appreciate it if someone could explain why and how to resolve it.
Thank you

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive...

Comment: use small n,  new EventEmitter();